A problem about fixed point of a continuously differentiable function

QUESTION

Let $f: (0,+\infty)\to(0,+\infty)$ be a continuously differentiable mapping
and there exist $k$ s.t.$|xf'(x)|≤kf(x)$
then $f$ has unique fixed point

My approach

I want to prove that $f$ is a contraction mapping,
so
$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\int_{x}^{y} f'(t)dt|<=\int_{x}^{y} \frac{f(t)}{t} dt$,but I don't know what to do after that……

sorry,k∈(0,1),i forgot to mention

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

let
$g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x^{\lambda}}$,
then
$g'(x) = \frac{f'(x)x^{\lambda}-f(x)\lambda x^{\lambda-1}}{x^{2\lambda}}=\frac{f'(x)x-f(x)}{x^{\lambda+1}}$
since $|xf'(x)|\le\lambda f(x)$,
$xf'(x)\le\lambda f(x)$
thus $g'(x)\le\frac{(\lambda-1)f(x)}{x^{\lambda+1}}$
so $g'(x)<0$,$g(x)$ is monotonically decreasing,and $f(x)=o(x^{\lambda})$
let $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$,and do the similar thing as $g(x)$,we have $h(x)$is monotonically decreasing
when $x \to 0^+$,since $f(x)=o(x^{\lambda})$,we have $h(x) \to + \infty$
when $x \to + \infty$,since $f(x)=o(x^{\lambda})$,we have $h(x) \to 0^+$
since $h(x)$ is monotonically decreasing,there is a unique c s.t. $h(c)=1$,namely,$\frac{f(c)}{c}=1$,$f(c)=c$

I've finally solved the problem,however,I failed to construct a solution using the contraction mapping,I still wonder if contraction mapping can be used in this problem.
